# I am not sure if I am writing the correct json return

Tags: node.js, express

I am able to return data from console log and as well as response json with the following code:

```
router.post('/contact/allcontact',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {  
  try{
      const contact = await Contact.find({id: {"$eq":sanitize(req.body.id)}}).sort({_id: -1})
      console.log(contact)
      res.json(contact)
  }catch(error){
      res.json({message:error})
  }
})
```

The console.log(contact) result as follow:

```
[{…}]
0:
contactgender: "Male"
contactname: "John Doe"
createdAt: "2021-04-19T08:30:34.184Z"
date: "2021-04-19T08:30:34.180Z"
updatedAt: "2021-04-19T08:30:34.184Z"
__v: 0
_id: "607d3faa249bb52b88b51f42"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to define my own fields when returning JSON such as:

```
router.post('/contact/allcontact',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {  
  try{
      const contact = await Contact.find({id: {"$eq":sanitize(req.body.id)}}).sort({_id: -1})
      console.log(contact)
      res.json({
        myContactInfo:[{
          myid:contact._id,
          mycontactgender:contact.contactgender,
          mycontactname:contact.contactname,
         }]
      })
  }catch(error){
      res.json({message:error})
  }
})
```

This is the result for myContactInfo:

```
{myContactInfo: Array(1)}
contactInfo: Array(1)
0:
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

but I am not able to return the data. Where did I go wrong? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? Is there an error message?

Comment: This is not a react question

Comment: So sorry, you are right it should have been express.

Comment: There isn't any error but it just an empty myContactInfo. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "but I am not able to do so"? Is the route returning `undefined` or are you getting an error or something else?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `console.log(contact)`?

Comment: hi Michael Hoobler, sorry for the vagueness. I am trying to define and return my own object such as myContactInfo and fields such as myid. By default, it will return _id ans so on. So this time I am trying to define my own fields. I am not sure if I have worded it correctly. Tahnks

Comment: hi  Ajeet Shah, thanks. I have edited the question with the output of the console log.

Answer (score 0):

This is an express js question.
To resolve your issue you need first of all to check the type of your contact variable , if it's a:

- String you need to make a string to json convert
- Array : you need to make a loop in your array and create your object and finally return it.
- Undifined: so you have an error.

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.